# JComboBox Option Selected Not Imposing Change

Tags: java, string, swing, jcombobox

In my code I have a simple JComboBox which is used to turn a certain feature on or off. The JComboBox code is:

```
public static JComboBox getErrorLoggingOnOrOff(){
    String[] options = { "On", "Off" };
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(options);
    return combo;
}
```

The issue is that this always returns the value as being on regardless of when I click "Off." The JComboBox is called here: *note that I have included the System.out.println()'s (and the check for null) just to check for output*.

```
String option = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
....
if(option.equals("On")){
    System.out.println("On selected");
    return;
}
else if(option.equals("Off")){
    System.out.println("Off selected");
    return;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Null value for option.... :-/");
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, genuinely baffled as to why this is occurring, no doubt a simple over sight.

Regards, Reg.

**EDIT**
Here is the full exerpt of code

```
 final JMenuItem enableErrorLogging = new JMenuItem("Enable Error Logging");
    enableErrorLogging.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_M, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    enableErrorLogging.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
    menu.add(enableErrorLogging);
    enableErrorLogging.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            if (ui.getWorkspace().getCurrentProject() == null) {
                openProjectMessagePane();
                return;
            }

            JComboBox combo = getErrorLoggingOnOrOff();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Turn Error Logging On Or Off"));
            panel.add(combo);
            String option = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();

            try{

            int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, panel, "Enable Error Logging?",
                    JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            if (r == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            if(option.equals("On")){                 
                System.out.println("On selected");
                return;
            }
            else if(option.equals("Off")){
                System.out.println("Off selected");
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Null value for option.... :-/");
            }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.debug(ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you provide a runnable version of the code, or is it too long?

Comment: It is probably too long... I will have a look for other exerpts that are potentially causing issues!

Comment: @bakalolo Put all code for this operation up there, disregard my previous comment. Thank you for your interest by the way.

Comment: Place`String option = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();` after your `if (r == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)`. I think you are getting the "selectedItem" before anything has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) for comparing Strings, **not ==**

i.e.

```
if(option.equals("On")) {
    // ...
}
else if(option.equals("Off")) {
    // ...
}
```

Here might be another problem:

```
JComboBox combo = getErrorLoggingOnOrOff();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
panel.add(new JLabel("Turn Error Logging On Or Off"));
panel.add(combo);

// Here, you seem to be getting the 'selected item' before even
// showing it using a JOptionPane, which I believe will be null by default
String option = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();

try {
    int r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, panel, "Enable Error Logging?",
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (r == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            if(option.equals("On")) {
                // ...
            }
    }
}
```

Place `String option = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();` after you call `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)`.

Comment: @Reginald Yes, quite sure that's it.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue... However, I'll edit the question to show this change.

Comment: @Reginald if you are comparing `errorLoggingStatus` with any other String, you will need to do the same.

Comment: @Reginald if this isn't solving your problem, maybe the problem is in some other parts of your code? Add some debugging text to check if the flow is correct?

Comment: Assigning that value to `String option` after `JOption.shpowConfirmDialog` solved my issue! Thank you very much! Can you explain why this is so? Sorry to bother you, just keen to learn from this and I don't understand why that was an issue!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79675/discussion-between-reginald-and-gosu).